# How to construct dynamical class with custom metaclass in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

As I read in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) I can create class dynamically but how to replace this class metaclass?

Should I just replace `type` metaclass with `SomeMetaClass`?

The question is very simple but simple help will be welcome too.

Comment: `SomeMetaclass.__new__("name", (object,), {})` ?

Comment: Yes, just use the name of your metaclass instead of `type`.

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you want to change the metaclass after class creation. If so, you can achieve it in the same way that you can change the class of an object. For starters, the initial metaclass needs to be different from type, the `__init__` and `__new__` of the new metaclass won't be called (though you can manually call `__init__` or a method that performs  `__init__`'s job).

```
NewClass = SomeMetaClass.__new__('NewClass', (object, ), {})
```

The `__new__` method is something similar to `__init__` and gets called prior to `__init__`. It will be clear with the following example:

```
In [1]: class Foo(object):
   def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
      print 'inside __new__'
      return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      print 'inside __init__'

In [2]: f = Foo() 
inside __new__ 
inside __init__
```

Execution sequence when `f = Foo()` is called is as follows:

- `Foo.__new__()` gets called
- It calls its parent's new method using `__super__`
- finally the `__new__` method of object is called, and the class is instantiated.
- Finally the `__init__` method of `Foo` is called.

Check [this](http://blog.fruiapps.com/2013/03/Yet-another-Python-MetaClass-Tutorial) for more info.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It looks I need to use `SomeMetaclass` metaclass instead `type` metaclass - whatever thank for suggestions.